# How does this query result make sense?

Tags: sql-server, inner-join, exists

Originally, I have a table called acc_account which lists all the accounts used by a company or organization. Lets say I have 518 rows in this table:

500 rows which are the accounts used and another 18 rows which describe the different type of accounts. It is used for creating reports in an accounting app. I don't know why they included 2 different parts into a table but it was created like that.

Anyways there is this stored procedure called acc_qry_chart_of_accounts, basically it lists down all the accounts that are used by an organization/company.

While studying inside the stored procedure itself, I found some problems understanding a query which is what I showed below.

Basically since there are 18 rows which are included together, some of those 18 rows must not be shown in the results, Eg: We don't have any account type of 'EI' (Extraordinary Income). I must exclude that from the results.

The query below is the example of what they used to exclude those accounts, I personally don't get why the parent column (aka parent_code) can be the same as the acc_code and why does it have to be using a different alias?

So, I decided to ask this question about the query itself which is why I'm here.

I inner join a table with itself using a different alias.
Then I create a query `WHERE` `EXISTS` the 'parent' column equals the 'acc_code' column, using this query:

```
SELECT * FROM acc_account 
INNER JOIN acc_account a2 ON acc_account.acc_code=a2.acc_code 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM acc_account WHERE acc_account.parent=a2.acc_code);
```

The result comes out like this:

```
acc_id   acc_code            parent           name
-------  ------------------ ---------  ---------------------------
2       |  CA              |  -1     |   CURRENT ASSETS 
3       |  CL              |  -1     |   CURRENT LIABILITIES
4       |  CP              |  -1     |   CAPITAL/RETAINED EARNINGS
5       |  CS              |  -1     |   COST OF GOODS SALES
7       |  EX              |  -1     |   EXPENSES
```

You can see that the parent data and acc_code data isn't equal in the first place but it produced the output above.

Now when I use the same query but changing the the last line previously `acc_account.parent=a2.acc_code` into `acc_account.parent=acc_account.acc_code`:

```
SELECT * FROM acc_account 
    INNER JOIN acc_account a2 ON acc_account.acc_code=a2.acc_code 
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM acc_account WHERE acc_account.parent=acc_account.acc_code);
```

The result:

```
acc_id   acc_code            parent           name
 -------  ------------------ ---------  ---------------------------
        |                   |         |
```

No results as it should be. So why in the first place if I tried to use a different alias, it produces different results?

The query below returns 0 rows:

```
select * from acc_account where parent=acc_code;
```

My question, `a1` & `a2` are same table or am I getting it wrong?

The condition `a1.parent=a2.acc_code` is it same as `a1.parent=a1.acc_code` in this case where both tables are same and contain same data?

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  It is unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: I edited my question, I cant really provide sample data but it should be understandable to some extent. Hopefully you could understand my problem

Comment: I added sample data, the query is a bit different but similar. Please explain why I get those 6 outputs when the subquery should return false.

Answer (score 1):

The query that you are writing is basically this:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM acc_account a INNER JOIN
     acc_account a2
     ON a.acc_code = a2.acc_code 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM acc_account a3 WHERE a3.parent = a2.acc_code);
```

There are *three* separate references to `acc_account`.  The `parent` referenced in the subquery has nothing to do with the parent being output.

Your modified query simply removes the correlation cause and no rows match, so nothing is returned.

Comment: can you explain actually how does the subquery evaluate it as true or false? The subquery in your answer shows that you return TRUE if the subquery runs smoothly or even when no rows are found?

Answer (score 0):

Your first query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM acc_account 
INNER JOIN acc_account a2 
    ON acc_account.acc_code = a2.acc_code 
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM acc_account 
    WHERE acc_account.parent = a2.acc_code
);
```

searches for parent `acc_account`s. The `SELF JOIN` here is insiginificant since you're using the same column in the `ON` clause. The result of the `SELF JOIN` would be the same without it. The `WHERE` clause then checks for parent `acc_account`s using this condition:

```
WHERE acc_account.parent = a2.acc_code
```

Your second query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM acc_account 
INNER JOIN acc_account a2 
    ON acc_account.acc_code = a2.acc_code 
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM acc_account 
    WHERE 
        acc_account.parent = acc_account.acc_code
);
```

is the same as the first except for the `WHERE` clause. Here:

```
SELECT * 
FROM acc_account 
WHERE 
    acc_account.parent = acc_account.acc_code
```

Since there are no `acc_count` that is a parent of itself, it returned no rows, resulting to the `EXISTS` condition to be `FALSE`, and the query to return no rows.

Note that since `acc_account` has bee referenced multiple times, two of which do not have an alias, the condition in the subquery:

```
acc_account.parent = acc_account.acc_code
```

references the table in the subquery, the nearest one, meaning your comparing the same row, but different column.

What you want is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM acc_account a1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM acc_account a2
    WHERE 
        a2.parent = a1.acc_code
);
```

This is where the importance of alias come into place.

Comment: can you explain in detail about the subquery `WHERE`  clause? You mentioned that it checks for the parent column right? Does it actually check if there are rows that equal the acc_code column?

Comment: Which query? The first or second?

Comment: the first which produced results

Comment: This part:   `SELECT * 
FROM acc_account a1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM acc_account a2
    WHERE 
        a2.parent = a1.acc_code
);`  I'm still confused, explain to me how does the subquery gets evaluated? a1 which is also a2 and both contains the same data inside, lets say `column a` contains name like `Jeff` and `column b` contains address like `no18, small street, washington`  lets say all rows are the same, so `Jeff` does not equal to the address in the first place, so it should return false right? So why are there results and changing the alias could do what actually?

Comment: I edited my question, help me explain why the output is like as shown